# WSO2 EI: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb, apache-axis, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm retrieving some data's from the DSS using select query after that, I do some transformation using payload factory and then send it to an endpoint but when I do that *First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html* error please help me to sort this out.

```
<sequence name="ValidateRecordExistanceInDB" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <p:select_with_key_novum_extension_operation xmlns:p="novum.service">
            <xs:Id xmlns:xs="novum.service">$1</xs:Id>
        </p:select_with_key_novum_extension_operation>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Extension')"
            literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value=""/>
<property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="POST"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
<property name="Accept" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
<property expression="$ctx:config//*[local-name()='localHost']"
    name="localHost" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
<header
    expression="concat($ctx:localHost, '/services/NovumAudioValidationDataRetrievalService')"
    name="To" scope="default" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
<property name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="select_with_key_novum_extension"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <default format="soap11">                
        </default>
    </endpoint>
</call>
<filter xmlns:ds="novum.service"
    xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="boolean(//ds:novum_extensionCollection/ds:novum_extension)">
    <then>
        <property expression="//*[local-name()='Department']" name="department"/>
        <property expression="//*[local-name()='Username']" name="username"/>
        <property expression="//*[local-name()='Extension']" name="extension"/>
        <property expression="//*[local-name()='Novum_Extension']" name="novumExtension"/>
        <property expression="//*[local-name()='email']" name="email"/>
        <property expression="//*[local-name()='location']" name="location"/>
        <property expression="//*[local-name()='selling_dealer__c']" name="selling_dealer__c"/>            
        <log level="custom">
            <property
                expression="concat('successfully retrieved record with extension ', $ctx:Rec_Id, ' from the db')" name="novum-api-status"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:department" name="department"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:location" name="location"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:username" name="username"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:email" name="notifierEmail"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:selling_dealer__c" name="selling_dealer__c"/>
        </log>
    </then>
    <else>
        <log level="custom">
            <property
                expression="concat('record with extension ', $ctx:Rec_Id, ' not found in the db, sending out error email notification')" name="novum-api-status"/>
        </log>
        <property
            expression="concat('Record with Novum Extension ', $ctx:Rec_Id, ' can not be found in the database.')" name="errorMsg"/>
        <sequence key="NotifyErrorSubscribers"/>
        <drop/>
    </else>
</filter>
```

[image: Log error]
[image: Script]
[image: Sequence 1]
[image: Sequence 2]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you enable wire logs and share the logs.https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Logs+in+WSO2+EI+6.6.0#LogsinWSO2EI6.6.0-Wirelogs(fortheESBprofile)

Comment: The ERROR occurs after the `</filter>`, so the question is: What are the next steps in sequence?

Comment: After that I'm using Script mediator in the flow.

Comment: You'll have to provide what you're doing after since the part you shared is working correctly. Usually when this error shows up you're calling some endpoint that returned HTML to you.

Comment: Hi Novren I've added the complete flow please check.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an HTTP page being returned by the laravel endpoint you've defined at the end. I recommend you turn on Wire logging via the config tab in the carbon console to see what exactly is being returned by the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, and I was getting html response from the endpoint instead of JSON response, but I couldn't see the html response so I enabled the following in **<EI_HOME>/conf/log4j2.properties** and restarted WSO2

```
logger.httpclient-wire-content.level=TRACE

logger.synapse-transport-http-wire.level=TRACE

logger.httpclient-wire-header.level=TRACE
```

After enabling logging I was able to see the response HTML which was a Support ID by Load Balancer

reference is : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Logs+in+WSO2+EI+6.6.0#LogsinWSO2EI6.6.0-Wirelogs(fortheESBprofile)

Also It's better If you enabled message formatters and message builders in **deployment.toml**

```
[[custom_message_formatters]]
content_type = "text/html"
class = "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"

[[custom_message_builders]]
content_type = "text/html"
class = "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"
```

Comment: This is the answer :)